# Why does scissor test happen after fragment shading?

Tags: opengl

In OpenGL why is scissor test performed after shading. Wouldn't be more efficient to do the discarding before shading?

[Reference pipeline overview](https://www.g-truc.net/doc/OpenGL%204.4%20Pipeline%20Map.pdf), the scissor test is inside the Fragment Processing stage.

Comment: There's a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808005/why-is-scissor-test-behind-fragment-operation) over on StackOverflow. What should we do?

Comment: If it's not a cross post, we do nothing (and it's not).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer: Scissor testing happens before fragment shading.

The scissor test *is* a per-fragment operation, so it is conceptually a part of fragment processing. According to the PDF that you linked, though, scissor testing is performed as the second step (right after Pixel Ownership Test) in fragment processing. This is before fragment shading.

In addition to that, the reference pipeline is only laying out how rendering should appear to work to the user. If something can be optimized further and still work the same way, rendering hardware designers are free to do that.